# Can I change the root EBS device of my amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EBS backed Amazon EC2 instance. I would like to change the root device on this instance. Can you please advise the best way to go about this?

I only find documentation on changing several attributes of block devices, but they don't seem to include setting it as the root device.

Comment: If you are using AWS web-based console, your instance doesn’t have any other volumes attached, and you are not sure what device ID you are supposed to use for boot volume, you can just attach a volume to your instance without specifying any ID and start the instance. AWS console will complain that there’s nowhere to boot from and tell you which device ID you should use (in my case it was `/dev/sda1`). You can then detach the volume and reattach, this time specifying that device ID.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Yep, it's dead easy:

1. Stop the instance.
2. Detach the root EBS volume.
3. Attach the alternate EBS volume as the root: **`/dev/sda1`** or `/dev/xvda` (based on AMI used)
4. Start the instance.

This presupposes that your alternate EBS volume is bootable, of course - it has to contain the bootable OS image.

Comment: If I detach the root EBS volume, the instance get terminated!

Comment: The AWS API (which the console uses) won't let you detach the root EBS volume from a running instance - but I'm not sure whether Force Detach obeys the same rule - did you do that by mistake? Or perhaps your instance is not EBS-backed, in which case this question/answer doesn't apply - I don't know what would happen if you tried to detach the boot volume from a non-EBS-backed VM.

Comment: The key is "as the root" -- `/dev/sda1` indeed!

Comment: Thanks, this is great. One gotcha is that the DNS/IP can change when this happens, so make sure to update any DNS / Elastic IPs, et cetera. I spent a while trying to figure out why I couldn't ssh into it anymore, and this was the reason.

Comment: I just did this but `/dev/sda/` worked for me and not `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer just saved me so much time! The "/dev/sda1" was very important for me (I tried it as just "sda1" the first time, but no root volume showed up).

Comment: Here is what you can indicate as letter http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

Comment: Thank you, is it the same case for reserved instances?

Comment: Don't forget to ensure that the new volume has the appropriate label or UUID.  For instance, on AWS Linux instances prepare the alternate volume by using `e2label /dev/your-alternate-volume '/'`.

Comment: Neither `/dev/sda` nor `/dev/sda1` worked for me, but `/dev/xvda` did.

Comment: Man, that was scary. `/dev/sda` -- didn't work. `/dev/sda1`, `dev/sdf` -- worked, but instance did't boot. `/dev/xvda` worked.

Comment: The name which you should use is the result of this command: `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-XXXXXXX | grep -i rootDeviceName` in my case `/dev/xvda`

Comment: I was thrown off by AWS’s hint, which reads “Windows Devices: xvdf through xvdp”. You can type `/dev/sda1` there and it’ll work.

Comment: just finished resurrecting one of the dead box, we have to provide the device name as /dev/xvda1. AWS doesn't allow you directly to use /dev/sda for the EBS volume. Here is the list which is assigned to instances based on HVM OR PVM.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

Comment: Note that you can not detach the Volume from the EC2 instance, you have to detach the EC2 instance from the Volume ;-)

Comment: The `/dev/sda1` was the key for me. **Do note the old device name** before detaching the old volume.

Comment: Somehow, mine was `xvda`... no leading `/dev/` on it, which caused my all kinds of headaches. Thanks @Neoecos for the tip on how to find out what the volume name was expected to be.

Comment: The key for me was that although amazon blocked attaching as /dev/sda, it allowed me to attach as /dev/sda1 and that worked.  
So behind the scenes AWS EC2 figures out the boot partition etc.

Comment: Is now apparently possible to do it on a running instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html#considerations

Comment: Yes, but beware the snapshot has to have come from the volume, so you can only do this once before requiring a new snapshot as the volume id will change.

Answer (score 49):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to the selected answer, but I do want to point out that for me, `/dev/sda1` did not work (did not attach as root), but using `/dev/xvda` worked (attached as root). The instance is one of the newer t2.micro ones using HVM.

Comment: I think the machines which are in VPC, device names of format /dev/xv* itself works and you do not need to give names in format /dev/sd*. This is an observation - I am no expert to say this with confidence.

Comment: I have an instance matching this description, which is unable to boot ("Unable to find root device") after detaching and reattaching the root device. I want to try this answer, but if I don't attach it as `/dev/sda1` then AWS refuses to start my instance. Is there some other setting I need to configure to use an alternate root device name?

Comment: /dev/sda1 for Linux /dev/xvda for Windows

Comment: whoopse, make sure to identify the partition, /dev/sda **1**, `/dev/sda` is invalid but `/dev/sda1` is fine.

Comment: And to add why it worked. this is why: https://superuser.com/questions/356533/whats-the-difference-between-dev-sda1-and-dev-xvda1#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20%2Fdev%2Fsda%20device%20is,the%20one%20you%20should%20use.

Comment: They probably want us to keep our "grubby" mitts off the bootloaders

Answer (score 19):

To elaborate on Diomidis Spinellis's comment in the the accepted answer's comments thread, it's important to check the filesystem label of the device you're attempting to switch in as your new root device. While troubleshooting my own server migration, I had to do the following before my instance would boot up:

Use the `e2label` command  to change the label on the ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem you've created for your new root device.

First, check the filesystem label for your current root device.

```
$ sudo e2label /dev/xvda1
cloudimg-rootfs
```

Set the new device to have the same filesystem label.

```
$ sudo e2label /dev/xvdg 'cloudimg-rootfs'
```

In my case, the label was `cloudimg-rootfs`. Sometimes it will simply be `/`.

It's important to understand how e2label works; check `man e2label` on your machine or visit http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2label for more information.

Comment: This is so incredibly important, I can't understand why this answer is not more commonly found.

Answer (score 6):

1. Stop the EC2 instance.
2. On Navigation panel, click '**Volumes**' under '**Elastic Block Store**'.
3. Choose the existing volume, click '**Actions**' and '**Detach volume**'. Complete the confirmation.
4. Choose the new volume, click 'Actions' >> '**Attach volume**'

   - In the **Attach Volume** dialogue box,
   - **Instance**: Enter *Instance ID*
   - **Device**: Enter `/dev/sda1`

Comment: Also note that the dialog implies that /dev/sda1 cannot be used, but ignore that and continue anyways, it works

Answer (score 3):

This is the aws suggested solution 
You can detach the root volume from the original instance after stopping it. The root volume is attached at /dev/sda1. Once this is detached, please attach it to the new instance. After the volume is attached, you may have to mount it from the OS. After it's mounted, you should see the data within it.

After you've done adding the new key, you can detach it and attach to the original instance at /dev/sda1.

I suggest creating a snapshot of the root volume before making any changes.

Before trying out any solutions just try out in the not important instances or spot instances

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to do this via CloudFormation you will need to do the following:

1. Create snapshot from existing root volume (via console or CLI)
2. Create new AMI from this snapshot - increase the root volume size here, make sure you select correct virtualisation time (paravirtual or HVM).
3. On your AWS::EC2::Instance resource, set the ImageId parameter to the new AMI you have just made

Deploy your stack. This will recreate your instance, so make sure you are using an Elastic IP address or have DNS access.

The reason you have to do this workaround is because CF will not let you adjust root volume size on EC2 BlockDeviceMappings, or to adjust SnapshotId of Root Volume.

Answer (score 0):

When your volume is mounted, it gets a post-fix with numbers, eg: when `/dev/sda` is mounted, its mounted as `/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2` depending on the partitions you make.
As we are mounting the root device itself, it assumes the device is already mounted, so we need to give `/dev/sda1` for mounting the volume as root device.
Note: There shouldn't be any root volume attached.

Follow these steps:
1) Go to your volumes, select attach volumes from Action.
2) Select your instance
3) For mounting as root, give the device name as `/dev/sda1`
4) Start your instance.

Answer (score 0):

Last week AWS announced new way to replacing Root volume with less downtime and Without Stop and Start EC2 instance. Please have a look below link.
[EC2 Replace Root Volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replace-root.html)