# Boot EBS volume from Bamboo instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2, bamboo, windows-server

I have an elastic instance that I have configured from within Bamboo to start on Amazon AWS EC2. I have created a volume from a snapshot which contains the OS (Windows Server 2008 R2) with various programs installed.

I am able to configure Bamboo to make the volume available as an extra drive using [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+elastic+instances+to+use+the+EBS), but I would like to actually boot this volume. I think this is similar to [making a root EBS volume from within AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377669/can-i-change-the-root-ebs-device-of-my-amazon-ec2-instance), but I am not sure how to do this from within Bamboo.

How do I boot a volume on Bamboo, rather than mounting it as an additional drive?

Edit: I have found a way to get the volume to mount automatically, which is a bit closer, but it would still be ideal to actually boot the drive. Here is the closest setting I see:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot boot EBS volumes, Bamboo or no Bamboo. You can only boot AMI images.

If you want to convert that volume to an AMI image:

1. Make a Snapshot (go to AWS Console, EC2, EBS Volumes, right click -> "Create Snapshot")
2. Create AMI (go to EBS Snapshots, right click -> "Create Image")

This will start creating the AMI image which you can later boot from "Images -> AMIs" page.

Bear in mind, there has to be a bootable OS on that volume.