# EC2 and EBS how and what are the differences?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an AWS EC2 machine I want to attach storage to which after its shutdown isn't deleted. The management should be done using Cloudformation.

I so far, do this using the following [snippet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html):

```
"BlockDeviceMappings": [
    {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda",
        "Ebs": {
            "DeleteOnTermination": "false",
            "VolumeSize": "10",
            "VolumeType": "gp2"
        }
    }
],
```

Reading also about [`AWS:EC2:Volume`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) and [`AWS:EC2:VolumeAttachment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volumeattachment.html) can somebody explain the differences? What are the benefits and disadvantage using one way over the other? How do I use the other methods together with an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AWS:EC2:Volume` just creates a new EBS volume. It's not Available for Use

`AWS:EC2:VolumeAttachment` allows you to attach the new volume to a running EC2 instance where it will be exposed as a block (storage) device.

So, you need to do `AWS:EC2:Volume` first to know the `VolumeId`, and then supply it to `AWS:EC2:VolumeAttachment`

```
{
"Type":"AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
"Properties" : {
   "Device" : String,
   "InstanceId" : String,
   "VolumeId" : String
}
}
```

You use `BlockDeviceMappings` when you create an AMI or when you launch a **new** EC2 instance.

You use `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment` when you attach an EBS volume to a **running** EC2 instance. You can attach multiple additional EBS volumes.

You can also attach and detach root device as mentioned here

> If an EBS volume is the root device of an instance, you must stop the instance before you can detach the volume.
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html

Comment: Can I add multiple devices this way? Can I use this volume as root partition?

Comment: Yes and yes. Refer to my updated answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377669/can-i-change-the-root-ebs-device-of-my-amazon-ec2-instance