# How to attach a former root volume of a terminated instance to a new instance as a root volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, partition, amazon-ebs

I had an EC2 instance with an EBS root volume attached. I detached the volume and terminated the instance. Then I created a new instance (different instance type, same AMI - Deep Learning Ubuntu 18.04). Now I'm trying to attach this old volume to this new instance as a root volume.

Although it seems pretty straightforward e.g. like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377669/can-i-change-the-root-ebs-device-of-my-amazon-ec2-instance), it doesn't work for me.

When I use `/dev/sda1` device for attaching the instance boots but I cannot ssh to it ending with `port 22: connection refused` although the port 22 was allowed when launching the instance.

When I use `/dev/sda` I end up with not being able to attach the volume (`Not a valid device name`).

I tried `/dev/xvda` but the instance won't start saying `missing root volume`.

I also tried reassigning elastic IP address after attaching the new volume. No change.

Does anyone have any other suggestion about what to try? I was thinking about maybe there is not ssh daemon running in this volume but how can I start it if I cannot connect to the machine. So maybe something else to try?